# How am I feeling the static electricity from my tennis racket?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity, everyday-life

After a lesson/hit, static electricity will often build up on my racket's strings from the repeated friction with the tennis balls. Sometimes, it will be strong enough that when I put the strings near my legs, it will feel as if the electrostatic field itself is pressing against my leg, almost like a blanket. How am I sensing the field on my body?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are answering your own question? Static charges are being transferred from ball to racket, and this net charge on the racket will then induce a charge in the hair on your leg, typically so that your hair will become attracted. This seems to be similar to rubbing a balloon against the hair on your head. Would you mind clarifying your question to exactly what you are in doubt about regarding this phenomenon, because you do seem to explain parts of it in the question already

Comment: I'm essentially asking how it is that I can sense the field with my body.

Comment: You're sensing your hairs being pushed apart by the charges repelling, giving a "hair-rising" effect.

Comment: Remember, post answers as answers, not as comments